# Printing specific number of key-value pairs in a hash

Tags: perl

I have a hash  which stores the count of key-value pairs, from an array of strings taken from an input document then sorts them and prints them.

```
%count = ();
foreach $string (@strings) {
    $count{$string}++;
}
foreach my $key (sort {$count{$b} <=> $count{$a} } keys %count) {
    print $key, ": ", $count{$key} ; 
}
```

so I am wondering is there a way to only print a certain number of key-value pairs in the hash instead of all of them ? i.e print top 5 based the value?

edit: would a for loop solve this?

Answer (score 4):

```
%count = ();
foreach $string (@strings) {
    $count{$string}++;
}
my $n=0; # variable to keep count of processed keys
foreach my $key (sort {$count{$b} <=> $count{$a} } keys %count) {
    # count processed keys (++$n) 
    # and terminate the loop after processing 5 keys  
    last if ++$n>5; 
    print $key, ": ", $count{$key} ;
}
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could explain what the code is actually doing so that future readers have a bit better of an understanding.

Comment: @stevieb I have added explanation comments

Answer (score 4):

Can take a [slice](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) of the list returned by sort

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

....

my %count;    
foreach my $string (@strings) {
    ++$count{$string}
}

say "$_: $count{$_}" 
    for ( sort { $count{$b} <=> $count{$a} } keys %count )[0..4];
```

(This expects that the hash indeed has five keys; if it can happen that that is not the case you'd get hit by warnings so add a test in that case, for instance `$_ and say "..." for ...`)

The code in the question is clearly not using `strict`; I recommend to *always* use it.

The `%count = ()` makes sense if the hash has been populated before and now need be emptied. If you are creating it then just declare (and without `= ()`, which does nothing).

---

Note, thanks to [Grinnz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5848200/grinnz): very recent [List::Util 1.50](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util) adds `head` (and `tail`) functions

Comment: The recently added [head/tail functions](https://perldoc.pl/List::Util#head) in List::Util can make this slightly nicer as well - it will avoid returning undefs if there are less than 5 keys. `use List::Util 1.50 'head'; say "$_: $count{$_}" for head 5, sort ... keys %count;`

Comment: @Grinnz Interesting! Didn't know about these.  Thanks for less-than-5 keys note ... added comments